# Saturation voltage in MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

V<sub>SAT</sub> is the saturation region boundary in the MOSFET characteristics.

In the text book it says V<sub>SAT</sub>=V<sub>GS</sub>-V<sub>T0</sub> but I can't see any explainations. Is there any reason for it?

Comment: This question might be useful: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/198064/saturation-regions-for-bjts-and-mosfets/198080?noredirect=1#comment413445_198080

Answer (score 1):

The saturation of drain current Ids occurs when Vgd=Vt (pinch-off condition of n-channel MOSFET).

So the saturation drain-source voltage is Vds=Vsat.

Since Vgd=Vgs-Vds you can find that Vsat=Vgs-Vt